# How to preserve selective faces messages across multiple pages?

Tags: jsf, message

We can ask JSF to keep faces messages intact to show on redirected pages using flash.
But I have a situation, where I have to show a warning message on all pages in a given session. I don't want to use flash because it will keep all the messages, which means even the error messages on a particular page will be propagated to other pages, where they don't make any sense. 
Does anyone know how to selectively retain faces messages?

Comment: You can keep them in session. Then in each given page you can try to recover them from session and display for the view. A `@SessionScoped` bean should be enough.

Comment: This question is easier to answer (even by yourself!) if you elaborate the technical conditions required for selection. Then it's just a matter of throwing them in an `if`.

Comment: You should provide a bit more information here. What do you mean by saying "show on all pages in a given session"? How long should they be preserved?

Comment: @BalusC How is this possible with an `if`? The `FacesMessages` will be automatically consumed once they were displayed, won't they?